# Issue with a program in C not correctly receiving the input

Tags: c, function

I'm having an issue with the output of this program. It is not correctly receiving the input. I believe it may have to do with my user defined function that acts as a scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14


int GetNum(void)
{
    return scanf("%d");
}

int CalculateAreaR(int length, int width)
{   
    return length*width;
}

double CalculateAreaC(int radius)
{
    return PI*radius*radius;
}

int main(void)
{
    int length;
    int width;
    int radius;
    int areaR;
    double areaC;

    printf( " Please enter the length of a rectangle  \n");
    length = GetNum();
    printf(" Please enter the width of a rectangle \n"); 
    width = GetNum();
    printf(" Please enter the radius of a circle \n");
    radius = GetNum();

    areaR = CalculateAreaR(length, width);

    printf("\nThe area of the rectangle is %d\n", areaR);

    printf("\nThe length is %d, the width is, %d and thus the area of the rectangle is %d\n\n", length, width, areaR);

    areaC = CalculateAreaC(radius);

    printf("\nThe area of the circle is %.3f\n", areaC);

    printf("\n\n The radius of the circle is %d and the area of the circle is %.3f\n\n", radius, areaC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enable warnings for your compiler and it should be clear.  You should hope to see `Warning: control reaches end of non-void function` (or similar).

Answer (score 8):

You could try modifying your program as this

```
int GetNum(void)
{ 
   int num;
   scanf("%d", &num);

   return num;
```

}

Comment: Thank You! Can you explain why the original function did not work?

Comment: In the original program, scanf requires an argument to read the data into, which was missing. An added point: if the code was written as `return scanf("%d", &num);` would return 1 i.e. number of parameters read. Hence, it is important to return the number read i.e. `num`

Comment: `scanf` can also return 0 or `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%d");` requires an additional argument. You need to give it an address of the variable you wish to store the number in. e.g. `scanf("%d",&length);`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the fact, that your GetNum function doesn't return any value at all:

```
int GetNum(void)
{
  scanf("%d");
}
```

Additionally in your call to scanf you forgot to supply a memory location to store the scanned number (if any).

Changing it to:

```
int GetNum (void) {
  int i;
  scanf ("%d", &i);
return i;
}
```

Should more or less solve your problem. To check if the scan was successfull you might also want to check the return value of scanf - it should return the number of successfully parsed items (1 in your case).

BTW: using the right compiler switches bugs like yours should be a lot easier to spot.

In case you're using gcc the switch -Wall would have given you the warning:
main.c:12: warning: control reaches end of non-void function